# Replace Bit Values (1) with Day names SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

with following query i select days (bit values) from my database into a string separated with blank space:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),BPL_MONDAY) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),BPL_TUESDAY) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),BPL_WEDNESDAY) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),BPL_THURSDAY) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),BPL_FRIDAY) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),BPL_SATURDAY) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),BPL_SUNDAY)
FROM BOS_PRICE_LIST
```

Result of the query looks something like this:

[image: Query result]

Now i want to replace 1 with current day name. Example of one row:

**Current query result:** 1 1 1 1 1 0 0

**What i want:** Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday

Thanks for help

Greetings

Comment: I believe you can use `case` [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) will help

Comment: Yes, I already tried with case but i cant get result as I want so I asked for help.

Comment: If you have already tried, it would be a good practice to share your trials and the results, so that it save time for those who would like to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT case when BPL_MONDAY = 1 then 'Monday' else  '' end + 
       case when BPL_TUESDAY = 1 then 'Tuesday' else  '' end +
       case when BPL_WEDNESDAY = 1 then 'Wednesday' else  '' end +
       case when BPL_THURSDAY = 1 then 'Thursday' else  '' end +
       case when BPL_FRIDAY = 1 then 'Friday' else  '' end +
       case when BPL_SATURDAY = 1 then 'Saturday' else  '' end +
       case when BPL_SUNDAY = 1 then 'Sunday' else  '' end 
FROM BOS_PRICE_LIST
```